# Implementing RichTextFX GenericStyledArea

Tags: java, javafx, richtextfx

I am trying to implement the RichTextFX `GenericStyledArea` into a program of mine, however, I cannot find an example which clearly shows how the program works in order to implement the feature and as such I have no idea how to implement it. If you could help show how a GenericStyledArea is setup and implemented that would be great or alternately provide another library with the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried out any of the demos at https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX#demos?  They include links to the source code used to create them.  The source code for several demos is available in the source under RichTextFX-master/richtextfx-demos/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/richtext/demo/ if you downloaded the source.

I'm new to RichTextFX as well (so weight my advice accordingly), but you might want to consider using one of the subclasses of GenericStyledArea like StyleClassedTextArea instead, depending on the functionality you need.  If those are unsuitable for you, then at least you can treat their source code as examples of how to use GenericStyledArea.

Comment: Ah, I was confused by the implemented elements of the demo because I assumed that the GenericStyledArea included all the elements shown in the demo by default which it did not and thus I thought the demo included a bunch of irrelevant information. Thanks for the help.